# When deserializing List of objects, JSON looks for a unexistent class

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, json-deserialization, jsonb

Using Spring I created a microservice that finds all messages in DB for a specific user.

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

@Autowired
private MessageRepository daoMsg;

@RequestMapping(value = "/Mensajes", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public List<MessageObject> enviados (@RequestParam("mail") String mail) {
    return daoMsg.findByEmisorOrDestinatario(mail, mail);   

}

}
```

DAO:

```
public class MessageObject implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
private String id;
private String emisor;
private String destinatario;
private String mensaje;
private String tipo;
private LocalDate fecha;
private String id_housing;

public MessageObject() {

}

public MessageObject(String id, String emisor, String destinatario, String tipo, LocalDate fecha, String id_housing) {
    this.id = id;
    this.emisor = emisor;
    this.destinatario = destinatario;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.fecha = fecha;
    this.id_housing = id_housing;
}
```

When calling the microservice from my client app:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    WebTarget webResource = 
   client.target("http://localhost:8082").path("Mensajes").queryParam(mail);
    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = 
    webResource.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    Response respuesta = invocationBuilder.get();
    int status = respuesta.getStatus();
    System.out.println("el status es "+ status);
    MessageObject[] listMessages = 
    respuesta.readEntity(MessageObject[].class);
```

stacktrace:

```
 javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error deserializing object from entity 
 stream.Caused by: javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Can't create instance of 
 a class: class [LMessages.MessageObject;, No default constructor 
 found.Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
 [LMessages.MessageObject;.<init>()
```

My client has the same MessageObject DAO as the one in the microservice, in:
[image]

**Question: why JSON is looking for a default constructor in LMessages.MessageObject if my MessageObject class is in package Messages (not LMessages)**

Comment: Could you change you return type of your rest method by changing List by ResponseEntity<List<YourType>>  and Add to your methode @ResponseBody?

Comment: Check if your import of MessageObject is correct on both sides (sever & client), you might be importing a different messageObject in one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Problem was i was using `.queryparam(mail)` without key - value structure, only key. Now using `.queryparam ("mail", mail)` works.